# Legend of Chart.js doesn't show up when receiving data from webservice

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, chart.js

I'm trying to create an App with Cordova and ionic and have a line chart in it where I display some purchase and delivery data.
I get the data from a REST webservice.

The problem I struggle with is, that the legend of the chart doesn't show up when I get the data from the webservice. Everything else works perfect.

My code is like this:

```
$scope.labels = ["00:00", "", "", "03:00", "", "", "06:00", "", "", "09:00", "", "", "12:00", "", "", "15:00", "", "",
  "18:00", "", "", "21:00", "", "", "24:00"];
$scope.series = ['Delivery', 'Purchase'];
$scope.data = [
  $scope.timeValues = RestTest.getRestDelivery(),
  $scope.timeValues = RestTest.getRestPurchase()
];
```

And this is my html:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-divider chart-header">
    Balance | Unit: KW/h
  </div>
  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true"
            chart-series="series">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use hard-coded data like this:

```
$scope.data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
];
```

everything works perfect. 
I just have this problem when receiving the data from the webservice.

In my opinion the legend trys to show up before the data from the service is received and without data there won't be any legend. 
Unfortunately I'm quite new to cordova/ionic and javascript/angular etc, so I'm not sure how to solve this problem.
Is there a way to show the legend even when I don't have any data?

Comment: Why not first getting the data and then rendering the chart? If you really want the chart to be visible with legend right away you could also just init the chart with some default values and then update the datasets when you retrieve your data, have you tried that?

Comment: Haha, that was just too easy to get the idea by myself :-D  
It works! Thanks a lot for the hint